# Getting swagger working with multiple microservices

Tags: .net, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, microservices

I'm interested in using swagger in our microservice architecture. Each microservice is written in .NET (WebApi2) and is a separate application (same host, however, just different paths). Ideally i'd like one swagger specification that describes all the APIs and would then like to use this to generate client side c# so all the consumers of these APIs have the definitions of the models and also the invokers for the services.

Is this possible to do? I've read it is since 2.0 but havent found any concrete examples. I've started playing around with some .NET swagger libraries and they all seem to install swagger-ui within the app itself - so each microservice effectively hosts its own API.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is kinda old,

But a simple solution would be to host a static site that links all swagger.

For future improvement: Implement one service that could discover all available Swagger within the server node when it boots and serve that one aggregated swagger site.

Answer (score 0):

**For, .NET + Ocelot**

1. Install the NuGet package, "MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot"
   i.e. dotnet add package MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot
2. Program.cs > Include blow lines in your code

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(builder.Configuration);

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(opt =>
{
    opt.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/swagger/docs";
});
```

3. Ocelot.json > Include the below lines

```
"SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "add your key",/* Your first microservice i.e customer, Order */
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "add your name",
          "Version": "add your version if any",
          "Url": "your microservice swagger json URL"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "add your key", /* second microservice */
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "add your name",
          "Version": "add your version if any",
          "Url": "your microservice swagger json URL"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

```
"GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "BaseUrl": "Add your main Ocelot gateway service url"
  }
```

4. **NOTE**: In, OCELOT.JSON - For all the "Routes" Include the below key,

```
 "SwaggerKey": "your key that is set above"
```

5. For Authentication, add the below code according to your auth setup (Basic Or Bearer)

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("basic", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "basic",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = @""
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "basic"
                                }
                            },
                            new string[] {}
                    }
                });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Description = @"",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
          {
              {
                  new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                  {
                      Reference = new OpenApiReference
                      {
                          Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                          Id = "Bearer"
                      },
                      Name = "Bearer",
                      In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                  },
                  new List<string>()
              }
          });
```

6. Refernce Link:
   https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot